Dynamic header and footer appearing in dev environment but not live deployment
Currently building a website for an archive community, and I am trying to implement a dynamic header and footer that loads on every page so that I don't have to hardcode them into every single html file.  I am currently encountering a problem where all the components show up just fine on localhost, but when I deploy it to a live demo on github none of the components load. I'm using relative paths, where index.html is in the root path of the site's source, and my global components file is in components/global/global.js. When I try to use absolute paths instead, nothing shows up on any environment. Any help is appreciated.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Dynamically adds favicon
    const addFavicon = () => {
        const link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'icon';
        link.href = 'favicon.ico'; // Relative path
        link.type = 'image/x-icon';
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    };

    // Fetches an HTML component and inserts it into the specified selector
    const loadComponent = (selector, url) => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`Failed to load ${url}: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
                }
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(data => {
                const element = document.querySelector(selector);
                if (element) {
                    element.innerHTML = data;
                } else {
                    console.error(`Element with selector "${selector}" not found.`);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(`Error loading component from ${url}:`, error));
    };

    // Initialize all global functionalities
    const initializeGlobals = () => {
        // Add favicon before anything else
        addFavicon();

        // Load the header and footer using relative paths
        loadComponent("#header", "/components/header/header.html");
        loadComponent("#footer", "/components/footer/footer.html");
    };

    // Initialize globals when the DOM is fully loaded
    initializeGlobals();
});


The paths in your code are not relative, they are absolute. To be relative to the current page, they would need to start with ./ or no /. Could you show the folder & file structure of the pages and components?

@blex whoops, sorry for confusing path labels. anyhow, here is my file structure:
code
├── [components]/
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── [footer]/
│   │   ├── footer.css
│   │   └── footer.html
│   ├── [global]/
│   │   └── global.js
│   └── [header]/
│       ├── header.css
│       └── header.html
├── index.html
├── [pages]/
│   ├── about.html
│   ├── add other pages here
└── └── faq.html
code

Okay, so copypasting the file tree didn't work, so for clarity: index.html is in the root, then there'is the pages folder and the components folder the next level down, then in pages are the other html files, and in the components folder there are subfolders for global logic, the favicon, header logic, and footer logic

and did you try what @blex suggested, i.e. loadComponent("#header", "./components/header/header.html");?

Do you get error messages?

@Argee I get 404's for header.html and footer.html in with inspect, but tbh i'm at a loss for why the live demo can't find the files. at this point i've tried both absolute and relative paths

Given that file structure, if your index.html is a the root of the URL (e.g. https://example.com/index.html), absolute paths (/...) should work, in theory. A relative path wouldn't work simultaneously on both the index.html and the other pages, as those are in a subfolder. What happens if you try to access the components directly in your browser? Are you sure they are publicly exposed?

@blex Bit of an update, but I did manage to get it to work somehow. I moved the js file up a level in the subdirectory and then tried using relative (../..) paths, tweaked the prepend and append logic for header and footer respectively, and it now works. Gonna do some more testing to see what exactly makes the code fail. I'll post an update to this thread when I figure it out.
